# Body onclick go to textarea

Tags: javascript, onclick, textarea

This may not seem like a useful script, but I need something that will basically allow the user to click anywhere on the page and the cursor will go to the textarea.

How I imagine this happening is by having  but I don't know that much about javascript to do this.

When the user clicks on the body, paragraph, image, or anything inside the body the cusor will automatically go to the textarea and he will be able to type in it.

I know this doesn't seem like it would be useful for anything, but trust me, I have a use for it. Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy with jquery. But how useful, I don't know.

```
$('body').on('click', function(){
  $('textarea').focus();
});
```

Comment: JQuery is a javascript library, and js is tagged.

Comment: I disagree, jQuery is a not bundled with browsers, so I think unless the OP tagged jQuery, it shouldn't be assumed that is present.

Comment: Thanks. It's awesome how fast people respond here!! (I'm new to StackOverflow) I'll try it out.

Answer (score 3):

Vanilla JS:

```
document.onclick = function(){ document.getElementById('yourIDHere').focus(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

without jQuery (pure JS):

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', 
function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].focus();
});
```